# Navigation bar Displaying incorrect

Tags: reactjs

I have a react front-end and I have created a login and registration view. Now, when I am loading up my landing page. It is displaying me the navigation bar for logged in user i.e. Home, User & Registration option. However, for non-logged in user it shall show the div of Home, Login and Register. Can someone check my sources and suggest a solution?

**Navbar.js**

```
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

class Navbar extends Component {
    logOut(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.removeItem('undertoken')
        this.props.history.push('/')
    }

    render(){
        const loginRegLink = (
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">
                        Login
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">
                        Register
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
        const userLink = (
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to="/profile" className="nav-link">
                        User
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
                        Logout
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark rounded">
                <button className="navbar-toggler" 
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbar1"
                aria-controls="navbar1"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggle-icon"></span>
                </button>   

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center"
                id="navbar1">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                                Home
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    {localStorage.usertoken ? userLink : loginRegLink}
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Navbar)
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Landing from './components/Landing'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Register from './components/Register'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <div className="container">
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**UserFunctions.js**

```
console.log("abc")
export const register = newUser => {
    return axios
    .post('/users/register', {
        first_name: newUser.first_name,
        last_name: newUser.last_name,
        email: newUser.email,
        password: newUser.password
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log("Registered");
    })
}

export const login = user => {
    return axios
    .post('/users/login', {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
    })
    .then(res=>{
        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
        return res.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the render of your `<Navbar />` component, I guess this should be change from

```
{localStorage.usertoken ? userLink : loginRegLink}
```

to

```
{localStorage.getItem('usertoken') ? userLink : loginRegLink}
```

And I noticed this one in your logout function:

```
logOut(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   localStorage.removeItem('undertoken')
   this.props.history.push('/')
}
```

Shouldn't it be `localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')`?

Hope this helps!